# Greatest Common Divisor using Euclidian Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, division, greatest-common-divisor

So I'm having a problem with my code here.

I am coding a Greatest Common Divisor using the Euclidian Algorithm and I can't seem to utilize the loop in order to keep the division to keep repeating until I get the greatest common divisor. So for now, I am able to get the remainder but do not know how to go on from there basically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int a;//Holds the first number
int b;//Holds the second number
int temp;//Assign to greatest number
int hold;//Assign to smaller number
float euclid;//soon to be function?
int leftover;
float gcd;



int main ()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to Brian Garnadi's Version of GCD!\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the first integer to be calculated: ";
    cin>> a;
    cout<<"Now enter the second integer: ";
    cin>>b;

    if (a>b)//Determines bigger number
    {temp=a;
        hold=b;
    }
    if (a<b)//Determines smaller number
    {
        temp=b;
        hold=a;
    }

    leftover= temp%hold;

    cout<<"\nThe remainder of the two numbers divided is "<<leftover<<".\n"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: I don't see a loop in the example code. If (a > b), then just swap a and b. No need for the second if.

Comment: Your code also fails if a = b

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no need to calculate bigger number the euclid's algorithm   manages itself.
Here's the working code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int m,int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return m;
    return gcd(n, m % n);
}

int main()
{
    int a,b,answer;
    cout<<"Welcome to Brian Garnadi's Version of GCD!\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the first integer to be calculated: ";
    cin>> a;
    cout<<"Now enter the second integer: ";
    cin>>b;
    answer = gcd(a,b);
    cout << "The GCD of the two numbers is : " << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to understand the algorithm and the code. If it's not clear , do let me know by commenting.

Comment: I've not handled any negative number case. You can do it if you want, implementing it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to handle negative numbers in algorithm.

```
gcd(m, n) = gcd(n, m%n)   when n != 0
          = m             when n = 0
```

function:

```
int gcd(int m, int n) {
    if(m == 0 && n == 0)
        return -1;

    if(m < 0) m = -m;
    if(n < 0) n = -n;

    int r;
    while(n) {
        r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: That function is NOT recursive.... which proves that you don't need a recursive method, iteration works just fine.

Comment: If n > m, then the first loop swaps m and n (effectively: r = m%n == m; m = n; n = r). Having a bigger number check will reduce the loop count by 1 (1 fewer divides), but it's not needed.